# Mount of device not owned by requested user

Tags: ubuntu, mount, uid

Using Ubuntu 18.04. When logging into a tty terminal of a PC, the `dmesg` lines

```
[   83.966238] Mount of device (uid: 0) not owned by requested user (uid: 1000)
[   83.966795] Reading sb failed; rc = [-1]
```

seem to explain this outcome `mount: Operation not permitted`. Then I am presented with the normal prompt.

The general `/home` is mounted and I can see `/home/user` (`ls -l home` gives `drwx------ 4 user user .... user`) as well its content.
This error does not occur if I login with another user in the same desktop.
This incident is part of a more problematic situation with that user and the loading of the encrypted content. If relevant please see: https://askubuntu.com/q/1372716/446253

I am not familiar with the concept of ownership at mount time.  Here, I am trying to isolate the meaning of the dmesg message first.

Which condition can throw that message?
Where should I look at first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error message is explained as follows:

> Mount of device (uid: 0) not owned by requested user (uid: 1000)

- "user (uid: 1000)" is the user that had the problem
- "device (uid: 0)" means that the device was not mounted
  (has no id).
- "not owned" is the actual error.

The reason for the problem is permissions : The user must be the owner
of both `home/.ecryptfs/user/.Private` and also of
`home/.ecryptfs/user/.ecryptfs`.
Owning only one of the two is not enough.